# Does PayPal Mobile Payments Library MPL run on iOS 5.1 with ARC?

Tags: ios, paypal

I haven't been able to get this working and all of the sample code seems deprecated.  I've been able to update a lot of constants, but does anyone have any sample.  I have a Sandbox App ID.  So far I've added the library, :

```
@interface PaymentViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *paypalButton;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // 1. spawn a new thread to initialize the paypal library
  // TODO: spawn a new thread
  [PayPal initializeWithAppID:SANDBOX_APP_ID forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];

  // 2. generate the 'pay with paypal' button
  self.paypalButton = [[PayPal getInstance] getPayButtonWithTarget:self 
                                                         andAction:@selector(payWithPayPal) 
                                                     andButtonType:BUTTON_278x43
                                                     andButtonText:BUTTON_TEXT_PAY];
}

  // 3. add the payment details
  // 4. wait for callback
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  I just got it working on iOS 5 with ARC.

Comment: How exactly did you achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since this was never actually answered, I'll go ahead and fill it out for others. Hope it helps.

You're going to need to find all placed in the library where it uses "assign" for a property definition and change any dynamic memory pointers to "retain", but leave any statically allocated variables alone.

For instance:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ListChoiceDelegate> choiceDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSArray *items;
```

CHANGES TO

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<ListChoiceDelegate> choiceDelegate; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *items;
```

but...

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger groupId;
```

stays the same.

Then you need to find all allocation that are wrapped with [[blah alloc ] autorelease]; and remove the wrapping autorelease and brackets:

```
[[[PaymentSuccessViewController alloc] init] autorelease]
```

BECOMES

```
[[PaymentSuccessViewController alloc] init]
```

Then remove any of these:

```
[super dealloc];
```